# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im facing this problem when inserting a SQL query:

`Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '30000001'', NULL, 'Pending', NULL, NULL)' at line 1`

**The code is:**

```
  <?php 
// Connecting to the MySQL server 

include "connection.php"; // Check connection 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM meet ORDER BY meetid DESC LIMIT 1"; $result =
mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); $last_val =
mysqli_fetch_array($result); //   print_r($last_val); $last_val1 =
$last_val[0];

$query = "SELECT * FROM hdr_student WHERE Stud_NO = '$stud_no'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$check_over = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$null = 'sss'; $validateon = '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000';
$supprephour = '0';

if(!empty($check_over['c_supervisor'])) 
{
      if(!empty($check_over['p_supervisor']))        
      { 
        $check_supp = $check_over['p_supervisor'];  
        $check_supp1 = var_export($check_supp,true);             

        $query = "INSERT INTO supervisorattendance (meetid, sup_no, supnote, supvalidate, supprephour, validateon) VALUES ('$last_val1', '$check_supp1', NULL, 'Pending', NULL, NULL)";       
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) 
        {  
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); 
        }  
      } 

      $check_supc = $check_over['c_supervisor'];  
      $check_supc1 = var_export($check_supp,true);     
      $query = "INSERT INTO supervisorattendance (meetid, sup_no, supnote, supvalidate, supprephour, validateon) VALUES ('$last_val1', '$check_supc1', NULL, 'Pending', NULL, NULL)";  

      if (!mysqli_query($con,$query)) 
      {  
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); 
      } 
}

?>
```

Comment: What is `supvalidate`, is that a Date field? How about `meetid` is that an `auto increment` `primary key`?

Answer (score 0):

you problem is about single quotes in your variable used in mysql

so escape them like this before use in mysql

```
 $check_supc = $check_over['c_supervisor'];  
 $check_supc1 = var_export($check_supp,true); 

 $last_val1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $last_val1);  // use this line
 $check_supc1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $check_supc1); // use this line

 $query = "INSERT INTO supervisorattendance (meetid, sup_no, supnote, supvalidate, supprephour, validateon) VALUES ('$last_val1', '$check_supc1', NULL, 'Pending', NULL, NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_export` tries to generate a string that's valid as PHP code.  Among other things, this means that if your content is a string, it'll get quotes around it.  Since you're also adding quotes while you're cobbling your SQL,  you end up with something like ...`''$check_supp1'', NULL, 'Pending', NULL, NULL)`.

Unless you have a good reason for using `var_export` here (and i'm about 94% certain you don't), get rid of it.  Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to make stuff safer for a MySQL query.

Or, if there's nothing but that number, you can use `intval` to make sure it's always a number.

Or, learn to use prepared statements.  :P  They can handle most of this stuff automatically.